# onClick listener returns bogus view after scrolling

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I have a grid layout inside a 2-D ScrollView, with a doubleClick listener to select an ImageView from the grid. My problem is that if the page is scrolled vertically, the view returned is not the one that's clicked on, but one from a row or two directly above it. Here's the modified ScrollView:

```
 public class VScrollView extends ScrollView {
    public HorizontalScrollView sv;

    public VScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public VScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public VScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        super.onTouchEvent(event);
        sv.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        sv.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }
  }
```

Creating the view:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar, container,  false);

        hScroll = (HorizontalScrollView) mView.findViewById(R.id.hScroll);
        vScroll = (VScrollView) mView.findViewById(R.id.vScroll);
        vScroll.sv = hScroll;

        gtCalendar (month,monthBlock);

        return mView; 

    } //end onCreateView
```

I use a doubleClick listener to avoid accidental selection while scrolling:

```
  public abstract class DoubleClickListener implements OnClickListener {

        private static final long DOUBLE_CLICK_TIME_DELTA = 300;//milliseconds
        long lastClickTime = 0;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            long clickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (clickTime - lastClickTime < DOUBLE_CLICK_TIME_DELTA){
                onDoubleClick(v);
            } 
            lastClickTime = clickTime;
        }
        public abstract void onSingleClick(View v);
        public abstract void onDoubleClick(View v);
    }

     public DoubleClickListener doubleClickListener = new DoubleClickListener()         {
           @Override
           public void onDoubleClick(View v){
               List<Integer> gridList = Arrays.asList(grid);
               int gridCode = action[gridList.indexOf(v.getId())];
               String there = String.valueOf(gridCode);
               Toast.makeText(getActivity(),there, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
           @Override
           public void onSingleClick(View v){
             }             

     };
```

Is there a way to make this work?